# How to hide bottom app bar on scroll in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an android application which has an activity and other activity implements the main activity.Now i am also implementing one activity many fragment pattern.So each activity has at least 7-8 fragment inside that.
Here is layout for my main activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/frame_lay">

</FrameLayout>



<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_appbar"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"

    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorbottomappbar"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_green_24dp">

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_two"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/logotwo"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp">


</ImageButton>
```

You can see that my main activity has frame layout in it in which i transact all the fragments.I used image button in place of floating action button as i want floating action button of oval shape.Now what i want that inside fragment when user scrolls then the image button , bottomappbar and the view which is horizontal line hides? The bottom app bar is being used in many fragments so i need a code which i can write in a activity which hides the bottomapp bar and the image button on while users scroll inside fragment.How can i achieve this? I am sorry for my silly question as i am new to android development .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by putting the below two lines in xml

```
app:hideOnScroll="true"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

So the full xml tag will be

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

Comment: and what about for image button and the view which is horizontal line just above bottomappbar

Comment: Keep in mind that If a FAB is present, it detaches from the bar and remains on screen.
Scrolling upward shows the bottom app bar, and reattaches to a FAB.

Comment: yeah i know that brother i am asking u that how i also hide the image button and the view

Comment: And use FloatingActionButton instead of your own image button.

Comment: If your are using scrollView or RecyclerView you can also hide the FAB by implementing onScoll listener.

Comment: can i make the floating action button in oval shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190223/discussion-between-abid-khan-and-abhi-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are scrolling inside a Fragment, you need to pass the scrolling values to your activity.

I suggest you use the default `InteractionInterface` that Android Studio generated in Fragment's template:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    root.scrollView2.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
        // the key is here.
        var delta = scrollY - oldScrollY
        listener?.onFragmentScrolled(delta)
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
}


interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // Name your function here
    fun onFragmentScrolled(delta: Float)
}

// the lines below are generated,
// not the key point here but important to binding listener
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    listener = null
}
```

And then, in `YourActivity`, implement `YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Override the function

```
override fun onFragmentScrolled(delta: Float) {
    anotherView.translationY = anotherView.translationY + delta
    if (anotherView.translationY > anotherView.height)
        anotherView.translationY = anotherView.height.toFloat()
    if (anotherView.translationY < 0)
        anotherView.translationY = 0f
}
```

the result will be like this [mp4 link](https://i.imgur.com/r370Nb3.mp4)

The main point is : Pass your scrolling action from Fragment to Activity,
You can achieve this in many ways, this is just the basic one;

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to Wesely's is the following.

Let assume we have something like this:
 [image: picture] 
A custom bottom appbar and we have at least one fragment per action.
What I mean is that activity main is the parent where all the fragments are going to place in.

You can declare an ***interface*** in main activity (in this example I want to hide/show a custom bottom appbar and FAB) to perform show/hide of the bottom appbar and fab (both of them in activity_main.xml), so the ***interface*** would look something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnScrollListenerMain {
...

    override fun fabAndBottomAppBarHide() {
        if (fab_main.isVisible) {
            fab_main.hide()
            bottom_app_bar.performHide()
        }
    }

    override fun fabAndBottomAppBarShow() {
        if (!fab_main.isVisible) {
            fab_main.show()
            bottom_app_bar.performShow()
        }
    }
...
} // end Main 

interface OnScrollListenerMain {
    fun fabAndBottomAppBarHide()
    fun fabAndBottomAppBarShow()
}
```

Once the interface is defined in main activity, every fragment with a Nested scroll view can implement it.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nsv_fragment_with_scroll"
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Creating a reference to the NestedScrollView and attaching the onScrollChangeListener will help us to check when there is a change in the scroll over the ***y*** axis

```
class FragmentWithScroll : Fragment() {
lateinit var mScroll:NestedScrollView
...
override fun onCreateView( inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_scroll,container,false)
        mScroll = view.findViewById(R.id.nsv_fragment_with_scroll)

        mScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener { v: NestedScrollView?, _: Int, scrollY: Int, _: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->
            val dy = oldScrollY - scrollY
            if (dy < 0) {
                (v!!.context as OnScrollListenerMain).fabAndBottomAppBarHide()
            } else if (dy > 0) {
                (v!!.context as OnScrollListenerMain).fabAndBottomAppBarShow()
            }
        }
        ...
        return view
    }
}
```

Remember in Kotlin we can use **_** when the parameter in the lambda is never used.
So basically the change in ***y*** is `val dy = oldScrollY - scrollY` and **dy** is negative **when the scroll is from bottom to top** and this condition `dy < 0` is true, so we use the context of the view to invoke `OnScrollListenerMain.fabAndBottomAppBarHide()` 
and again **dy** is positive **when the scroll is from top to bottom** and this condition `dy > 0` is true, so we use the context of the view to invoke `OnScrollListenerMain.fabAndBottomAppBarShow()`

But, what if we just want to hide a BottomAppbar (without hiding FAB)?

The BottomAppbar might be child of Coordinator layout and the fragments need to have a NestedScrollView, RecyclerView or ScrollView as parent in their XML, so the main activity XML should look something like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lly_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:hideOnScroll="true">
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragments should be placed into **lly_main** and this line makes the trick: `app:hideOnScroll="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the following attribute to your `BottomAppBar`:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
```

Comment: and what about for image button and the view which is horizontal line just above bottomappbar

Comment: For the reset of the elements I would suggest to listen for scroll change of the recycler view and hide/show them based on the value of `dy`.